# rails: Accessing member variables in after_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, after-create

I am building a survey app where, based on ratings I need certain things to happen.
Basically, if a survey is submitted with a total rating under 15, we need to notify a supervisor. That's easy enough with mailers, but I can't seem to access the rating data in an after_create method.

My model has 5 fields named A,B,C,D, and E which are integers and they hold the rating data in the form.

I have tried :notation I have tried self.notation, I've tried after_create(service) service.notation and nothing works - the email never gets sent because it doesn't realize that the rating is lower than 15.

I also have a checkbox with similar issues. In the database it appears as "true" but before it is saved it usually shows up as 1 so testing for the correct value is tricky. Similar to the code below, I can't access it's value either. I've listed all the various methods I've tried with no success.

**Obviously these are not all existent in the model at the same time, they are listed below as examples of what I have attempted**

How do I access these data values in an after_create call?!

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :lowScore

  def lowScore
    if(A+B+C+D+E) < 15 #does not work
      ServiceMailer.toSupervisor(self).deliver
    end
  end

  def lowScore
    if(self.A+self.B+self.C+self.D+self.E) < 15 #does not work either
      ServiceMailer.toSupervisor(self).deliver
    end
  end

  #this does not work either!
  def after_create(service)
    if service.contactMe == :true || service.contactMe == 1
      ServiceMailer.contactAlert(service).deliver
    end
    if (service.A + service.B + service.C + service.D + service.E) < 15
      ServiceMailer.toSupervisor(service).deliver
      ServiceMailer.adminAlert(service).deliver
    end
  end
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what happens? if you stick a breakpoint in your lowScore method, what are your object's attributes?

Comment: I figured it out, and I feel like an idiot. I will post my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a solution.

In model.rb:

```
  after_create :contactAlert, :if => Proc.new {self.contactMe?}
  after_create :lowScore, :if => Proc.new {[self.A, self.B, self.C, self.D, self.E].sum < 15}

  def contactAlert
    ServiceMailer.contactAlert(self).deliver
  end

  def lowScore
    ServiceMailer.adminAlert(self).deliver
    ServiceMailer.toSupervisor(self).deliver
  end
```

The key was using the Proc.new to do the tests for conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Do debug:

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :low_score
  def low_score
    # raise (A+B+C+D+E).inspect # uncomment this line to debug your code
    # it will raise exception with string containing (A+B+C+D+E). See what is result this line in your console tab where rails server started
    # Or you can see result in your browser for this raise
    ServiceMailer.toSupervisor(self).deliver if (A+B+C+D+E) < 15
  end
end
```